# Windows process structure: How to store user information?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, kernel

I want to store some information in the EPROCESS structure of the process in windows NT kernel. My aim is that when winlogon is called I want to assign a unique value to the next process based on which user logs in. But I do not know where to store this unique ID. I have tried and succeeded in modifying some information (like the tokens) in the EPROCESS block of a process by the method of Direct kernel object modification and I wonder if there is any structure in this EPROCESS block where some other information can be stored.

p.s. For modifying the EPROCESS block I used a device driver.

Comment: Could you explain the broader context of this requirement?  Would it be possible for you to instead store the "process => unique ID" mapping in one  centralized table maintained by 1 process (and provide some mechanism for other processes to query it, if necessary)?

Answer (score 3):

The EPROCESS structure is opaque and undocumented, meaning you shouldn't be messing with its internals. Doing so requires you, among other things, to test on every OS version and service pack you plan on supporting.

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify EPROCESS.  It will bring you great sorrow.

Furthermore, if you do, do not install it on anyone elses machine.  It is absolutely wrong to impose such a profoundly damaging, system destabilizing change on another persons computer.  How would like it if I gave you tuberculosis?